# Is there a map of all the points at which it's possible to get onto Interstate 88?

Tags: burnout-paradise

I often wonder if I am missing some convenient locations at which I could get onto the I-88 in Burnout Paradise. The Burnopedia does not appear to attempt to list all such locations. Has anyone seen such a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was about to start making my own, so I searched for high-res images of the Burnout Paradise maps.

What I found instead was an answer to this question:

http://www.senocular.com/burnout/?load=i88.xml

It's not the most readable, but it does appear to be comprehensive. It also doesn't seem to indicate the path one must take to get on/off at the trickier points. Still, fairly useful.

Bonus: there are lots of other Burnout Paradise maps linked at the bottom!

Answer (score 1):

I don't ever remember seeing one. Most of the maps I found online never quite met my needs.